# Can Time Machine be setup to back up only one folder?

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine, backup

I am beginning to make a project on my Mac, let's call it MyProject, and it's the only thing on this computer that is worth backing up.

Therefore, I will only need Time Machine to back up just the folder of my project (and everything that is on that folder including any subfolders).

(as an irrelevant note, back up devices will include encrypted thumb drives)

tl;dr:
So here goes my question, let's say that I need Time Machine to backup everything on /users/MyName/MyProject and nothing else, how can I get it to do that?

Comment: Although if your hard disk breaks how will you get back things like your preferences?

Comment: I would restore them by hand...

Comment: Actually, thank you for asking this it made me think a lot. For instance, I should encrypt only that folder, not the entire HDD through Apple's apps, there's many reasons why I should do that!!! Thank you :))) <3

Comment: To make you think more " would restore them by hand..." - from what? It is easier to have TM do it all

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. However, you can exclude individual folders from Time Machine.

[HT1427 Mac Basics: Time Machine:](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427)

> ### Selecting items to exclude from the backup
>
> In Time Machine preferences you can click the Options button to adjust settings. A sheet similar to this appears when you click Options:
>
> [image: Time machine preferences screen shot]

It may be possible using the command line utility [`tmutil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html) however

Comment: Yeah, I see, it doesn't look like Time Machine can be set up to back up only specific folders.
I will send a request to Apple to ask them to implement such a feature, and until they do (if ever) I will look for third party back up software that suits my needs.